# Вылетает MySQLWorkbench: Segmentation fault

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench

MacOS, Sonoma 14.0
Как только нажимаю на любую модель, сразу же вылетает Workbench и выдает такую ошибку

```
    -------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               MySQLWorkbench [62325]
Path:                  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
Identifier:            com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
Version:               8.0.34.CE (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-10-20 14:08:00.7133 +0300
OS Version:            macOS 14.0 (23A344)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     8.0 (21P365)
Anonymous UUID:        E400A76F-BF85-D586-9F6D-6AC1087798C5

Sleep/Wake UUID:       73D67BBC-193C-442D-A242-5A3BB76EF7A8

Time Awake Since Boot: 240000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3349 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000000e0
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000000000e0

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [62325]

VM Region Info: 0xe0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 140737488199456
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      shared memory            7ffffffda000-7ffffffdb000 [    4K] r-x/r-x SM=SHM  

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libmforms.dylib                        0x106a19153 mforms::ToolBar::find_item(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) + 17
1   libmforms.dylib                        0x106a193a5 mforms::ToolBar::get_item_checked(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) + 9
2   WBExtras                               0x1057adbf0 -[WBSidebarPanel splitViewDidResizeSubviews:] + 384
3   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d707b0 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 137
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800e01436 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 88
5   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800e01380 _CFXRegistrationPost + 532
6   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d406bb _CFXNotificationPost + 682
7   Foundation                          0x7ff801cbd7a7 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 82
8   AppKit                              0x7ff804c55bfc -[NSSplitView _sendDidResizeNotificationsIfNecessary] + 392
9   AppKit                              0x7ff804c557cc -[NSSplitView _compareDividerFramesAndNotifyWithOldFrames:viewWasResized:] + 513
10  AppKit                              0x7ff804492b89 -[NSSplitView setAutosaveName:] + 104
11  MySQLWorkbench                         0x104c8c877 -[WBModelOverviewPanel init] + 645
12  MySQLWorkbench                         0x104c8b2f6 -[MainWindowController(MainWindowControllerModel) handleModelCreated] + 22
13  MySQLWorkbench                         0x104c5c312 -[MainWindowController refreshGUI:argument1:argument2:] + 413
14  MySQLWorkbench                         0x104c69ba1 windowRefreshGui(wb::RefreshType, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, void*, MainWindowController*) + 31
15  libwbprivate.be.dylib                  0x10790d260 std::__1::function<void (wb::RefreshType, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, void*)>::operator()(wb::RefreshType, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, void*) const + 38
16  libwbprivate.be.dylib                  0x10790d091 wb::WBContext::flush_idle_tasks(bool) + 293
17  MySQLWorkbench                         0x104c6b686 -[WBMainController flushIdleTasks:] + 50
18  Foundation                          0x7ff801dcfb9c __NSFirePerformWithOrder + 357
19  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d7a836 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
20  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d7a75a __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 493
21  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d79cdc __CFRunLoopRun + 850
22  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d79372 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
23  HIToolbox                           0x7ff80b5e59d9 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
24  HIToolbox                           0x7ff80b5e57e6 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 665
25  HIToolbox                           0x7ff80b5e5531 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 66
26  AppKit                              0x7ff8043810c5 _DPSNextEvent + 880
27  AppKit                              0x7ff804c72150 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1304
28  AppKit                              0x7ff80437263a -[NSApplication run] + 603
29  AppKit                              0x7ff804346670 NSApplicationMain + 816
30  dyld                                0x7ff8009173a6 start + 1942

Thread 1::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff800c60a2e mach_msg2_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff800c6ee4a mach_msg2_internal + 84
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff800c67b6e mach_msg_overwrite + 653
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff800c60d1f mach_msg + 19
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d7b475 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 143
5   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d79ee5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
6   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d79372 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
7   Foundation                          0x7ff801d10bd1 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 216
8   AppKit                              0x7ff80482b7cf -[NSAnimation _runBlocking] + 465
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800af72e6 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800af859a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800b0799d _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 879
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800b07f22 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 152
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9cc06 _pthread_wqthread + 262
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9bb97 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 2::  Dispatch queue: NSTextCheckingOperationQueue (QOS: USER_INTERACTIVE)
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x7ff800abe95d nanov2_calloc + 114
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff8008d3902 realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*) + 134
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff8008ed89e realizeClassMaybeSwiftMaybeRelock(objc_class*, locker_mixin<lockdebug::lock_mixin<objc_lock_base_t>>&, bool) + 318
3   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff8008d6d01 lookUpImpOrForward + 680
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff8008d649b _objc_msgSend_uncached + 75
5   AppKit                              0x7ff80459ae44 -[NSXPCSpellServerClient contextForMessageName:waitForReply:] + 30
6   AppKit                              0x7ff80459ade1 -[NSXPCSpellServerClient _recordResponse:toCorrection:forWord:language:] + 52
7   AppKit                              0x7ff80459abab __findServer_block_invoke + 185
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800af859a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800af97cb _dispatch_once_callout + 20
10  AppKit                              0x7ff80459a9a8 -[NSSpellChecker _findServerWithSelectedIndex] + 454
11  AppKit                              0x7ff80461faf5 -[NSSpellChecker _chosenSpellServer:launchIfNecessary:] + 167
12  AppKit                              0x7ff804c4569c -[NSSpellChecker candidatesForSelectedRange:inString:types:options:offset:orthography:inSpellDocumentWithTag:] + 2117
13  AppKit                              0x7ff8045894f8 NSSpellCheckerCheckString + 1785
14  AppKit                              0x7ff8050c0976 -[NSTextCandidateOperation main] + 257
15  Foundation                          0x7ff801cf30cb __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 17
16  Foundation                          0x7ff801cf236c -[NSOperation start] + 730
17  Foundation                          0x7ff801cf208d __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
18  Foundation                          0x7ff801cf1f5e __NSOQSchedule_f + 182
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800af72e6 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800af859a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800afb0c7 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 523
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800afa73c _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 710
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800b07776 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 328
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800b07f22 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 152
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9cc06 _pthread_wqthread + 262
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9bb97 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9bb88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9bb88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9bb88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9bb88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9bb88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9bb88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9bb88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:: GRTDispatcher
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff800c635d6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800ca079c _pthread_cond_wait + 1260
2   libglib-2.0.0.dylib                    0x105ab160b g_cond_wait_until + 123
3   libglib-2.0.0.dylib                    0x105a25636 g_async_queue_pop_intern_unlocked + 166
4   libglib-2.0.0.dylib                    0x105a25798 g_async_queue_timeout_pop + 56
5   libwbpublic.be.dylib                   0x106116499 bec::GRTDispatcher::worker_thread(void*) + 209
6   libglib-2.0.0.dylib                    0x105a85df2 g_thread_proxy + 66
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800ca0202 _pthread_start + 99
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9bbab thread_start + 15

Thread 11:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff800c60a2e mach_msg2_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff800c6ee4a mach_msg2_internal + 84
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff800c67b6e mach_msg_overwrite + 653
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff800c60d1f mach_msg + 19
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d7b475 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 143
5   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d79ee5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
6   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800d79372 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
7   AppKit                              0x7ff8044de3e0 _NSEventThread + 122
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800ca0202 _pthread_start + 99
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff800c9bbab thread_start + 15


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007ff7bb2ab221  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x6c67676f742e6277  rdx: 0x0000000000000008
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00007ff7bb2ab220  rbp: 0x00007ff7bb2ab110  rsp: 0x00007ff7bb2ab0c0
   r8: 0x7261626564695365   r9: 0x00000000cce4037d  r10: 0x00007ff8442a1d80  r11: 0x00007ff6b5af419d
  r12: 0x0000000000000060  r13: 0x00007f8fdcdec240  r14: 0x000060000105a860  r15: 0x0000600002fbe0d0
  rip: 0x0000000106a19153  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x00000000000000e0
  
Logical CPU:     4
Error Code:      0x00000004 (no mapping for user data read)
Trap Number:     14

Thread 0 instruction stream:
  ff 48 89 c3 4c 89 ff e8-59 ff ff ff 4c 89 f7 e8  .H..L...Y...L...
  91 05 f6 ff 48 89 df e8-e1 9f f4 ff 90 90 90 90  ....H...........
  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90-90 55 48 89 e5 5d e9 62  .........UH..].b
  ff ff ff 55 48 89 e5 53-50 48 89 fb e8 54 ff ff  ...UH..SPH...T..
  ff 48 89 df 48 83 c4 08-5b 5d e9 9c f9 02 00 55  .H..H...[].....U
  48 89 e5 41 57 41 56 41-55 41 54 53 48 83 ec 28  H..AWAVAUATSH..(
 [4c]8b a7 e0 00 00 00 4c-3b a7 e8 00 00 00 0f 84  L......L;....... <==
  ee 00 00 00 49 89 f5 49-89 ff 4c 8d 75 c1 48 8d  ....I..I..L.u.H.
  46 01 48 89 45 b0 48 8d-5d c0 48 89 75 b8 49 8b  F.H.E.H.].H.u.I.
  34 24 48 83 c6 20 48 89-df e8 91 f7 02 00 0f b6  4$H.. H.........
  4d c0 48 89 c8 48 d1 e8-48 89 c2 f6 c1 01 74 04  M.H..H..H.....t.
  48 8b 55 c8 41 0f b6 7d-00 40 f6 c7 01 74 06 49  H.U.A..}.@...t.I

Binary Images:
       0x11b4dd000 -        0x11b4e0fff com.apple.icloud.drive.fileprovider.override (1.0) <9ed5a6be-94ce-3522-bf98-52d2b97d8642> /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/iCloudDriveFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iCloudDriveFileProviderOverride
       0x11b53a000 -        0x11b555fff com.apple.findersync.fileprovideroverride.FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (14.0) <2ec27c6e-4874-39e5-bf40-b9d12d9bfbc6> /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride
       0x1193ca000 -        0x1193d1fff com.apple.FileProviderOverride (1681.1.8) <583d91ec-36da-3394-8233-6fc5736eb542> /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FileProviderOverride
       0x116877000 -        0x11687efff com.oracle.workbench.wb-editors (*) <f9634b34-afd0-39b6-aa33-476790c91de3> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/wb.model.editors.mwbplugin/Contents/MacOS/wb.model.editors
       0x116975000 -        0x116994fff com.oracle.workbench.deb-editors (*) <888e4fbb-c52e-3209-be69-66fa0715a825> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db.mysql.editors.mwbplugin/Contents/MacOS/db.mysql.editors
       0x1165c9000 -        0x1165ccfff com.oracle.workbench.printing (*) <8c459f65-8ada-303d-9332-7dc92ddcb302> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/wb.printing.mwbplugin/Contents/MacOS/wb.printing
       0x11667e000 -        0x116691fff wb.model.snippets.wbp.dylib (*) <54f3d824-fa3a-3381-900a-e8e62d3e1977> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/wb.model.snippets.wbp.dylib
       0x116a1e000 -        0x116a45fff db.search.wbp.dylib (*) <07478f18-2d2c-38fb-bea0-642b5dbba8f5> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db.search.wbp.dylib
       0x1168d5000 -        0x1168fcfff db.mysql.diff.reporting.wbp.dylib (*) <74442713-5719-3cee-8f9c-195ab356567e> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db.mysql.diff.reporting.wbp.dylib
       0x116bdb000 -        0x116c8efff db.mysql.wbp.dylib (*) <5334b8ad-694d-37d7-97e1-3a09321624c4> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db.mysql.wbp.dylib
       0x116602000 -        0x11661dfff wb.model.editors.wbp.dylib (*) <359883b0-249f-3750-b915-becc845c8c5a> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/wb.model.editors.mwbplugin/Contents/Frameworks/wb.model.editors.wbp.dylib
       0x1166df000 -        0x116736fff db.mysql.editors.wbp.dylib (*) <b4331d44-3be4-3c0f-aee6-7ac0c26f3f83> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db.mysql.editors.mwbplugin/Contents/Frameworks/db.mysql.editors.wbp.dylib
       0x116555000 -        0x116564fff wb.printing.wbp.dylib (*) <3719aa61-3e05-3c00-a6af-1fa10d2ee3d1> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/wb.printing.mwbplugin/Contents/Frameworks/wb.printing.wbp.dylib
       0x115ce7000 -        0x115cf2fff _sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <a1f82f7b-6edd-31cf-8281-8b873b5c8223> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x1162cb000 -        0x1162f2fff _cairo.so (*) <4c4dcc25-6c7d-3e06-b070-074102b849d3> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries/_cairo.so
       0x115d0d000 -        0x115d10fff termios.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <394e895f-f85b-3c3f-b3ce-a058f579df28> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/termios.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x115b91000 -        0x115ba4fff _ctypes.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <6ffdb540-1067-33b0-be3f-15905dc32b39> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x115807000 -        0x11580afff _opcode.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <7a9c58c4-772d-3707-b10c-14b41443a7aa> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x115bd3000 -        0x115bdafff binascii.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <49316cd5-1020-378b-b105-227ba27b4121> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/binascii.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x115bbf000 -        0x115bc6fff _json.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <4e3ed96a-09e2-30eb-b5a3-94c1a07de1b1> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_json.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x115909000 -        0x115910fff _csv.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <63e3106d-fe39-3a46-840c-8f07d93df5b6> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_csv.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x1158e9000 -        0x1158fcfff _datetime.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <5aee50a8-9802-3957-8e52-3f99616973a7> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_datetime.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x1157f3000 -        0x1157fafff _sha512.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <9405ca12-a3d5-3d36-8d2c-1eaa5104b9d0> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sha512.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x115819000 -        0x11581cfff _random.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <763e7d51-ea7b-3f86-9325-bff4bd52c75a> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x1155b5000 -        0x1155b8fff _bisect.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <73a61772-d027-3090-8939-4eab1e2943cd> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x1155a1000 -        0x1155a8fff _lzma.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <f972478c-97c0-3104-87e8-6369c17d1093> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x10acc2000 -        0x10acc5fff _bz2.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <fff36db5-1a21-3738-b1d6-a1f66a42b2d1> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x10acae000 -        0x10acb5fff zlib.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <039631aa-1caa-335b-8c82-f3d686bc5d59> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x115591000 -        0x115594fff _posixsubprocess.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <aab9dcdc-11dd-3293-9463-5bc89806d817> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x10acd4000 -        0x10acd7fff grp.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <5f175ed5-8cf5-3e8e-9679-1ed84745d72a> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x115d22000 -        0x115df9fff _mforms.so (*) <036fa42b-e89b-33cd-9fda-d0b07c5c955a> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries/_mforms.so
       0x115479000 -        0x115484fff array.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <ac7f9c47-a34c-36f7-802d-c451357c9168> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/array.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x115465000 -        0x11546cfff select.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <36cc70e7-e8f1-38f5-8980-502fde4d0306> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/select.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x107492000 -        0x10749dfff math.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <5d91766d-8b8d-3df8-93ef-1d01b5091e6b> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/math.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x10a182000 -        0x10a191fff _socket.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <88abfb99-2b82-3d5f-855f-0948ed5896a5> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x1077ea000 -        0x107801fff _pickle.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <6be504ee-98eb-3f08-a1ba-d22cc02434e1> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x107047000 -        0x10704efff _struct.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <122ca4e3-b67e-3844-829d-c40e1989e0ff> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x105d40000 -        0x105d43fff _queue.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <eb88f1fc-7ba0-378c-9561-39626188160a> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_queue.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x10a162000 -        0x10a169fff utilities.grt.dylib (*) <43486fe7-9d9c-36d0-aaf5-0368579ad4c4> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/utilities.grt.dylib
       0x1155cb000 -        0x115646fff db.mysql.sqlparser.grt.dylib (*) <bb625a26-b1bc-3363-8c71-34b363911c6a> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db.mysql.sqlparser.grt.dylib
       0x115921000 -        0x115a6cfff sql.parser.dylib (*) <6c4fd08b-cc27-3be8-a365-a362bf1d3bc3> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/sql.parser.dylib
       0x1153cd000 -        0x115404fff wb.model.grt.dylib (*) <177258fa-10b8-3caa-a42a-518fa0316e5c> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/wb.model.grt.dylib
       0x10aa9f000 -        0x10aab2fff db.mysql.query.grt.dylib (*) <33f8cbdf-026a-3d75-8b42-031fa1ca8e52> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db.mysql.query.grt.dylib
       0x10ab26000 -        0x10ab89fff db.mysql.grt.dylib (*) <53504d28-1715-309d-bb55-9523fce0c0ea> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db.mysql.grt.dylib
       0x11522d000 -        0x115294fff db.mysql.parser.grt.dylib (*) <f2639d5b-6a3d-3460-8d58-d17d1aa87ff0> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db.mysql.parser.grt.dylib
       0x105d09000 -        0x105d0cfff _heapq.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <79a02239-d1cf-3093-8596-4b742e396609> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x105491000 -        0x1054a0fff libobjc-trampolines.dylib (*) <c43ce21c-a026-37b5-95ee-ef39fd2196de> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
       0x105201000 -        0x105238fff libwbbase.dylib (*) <d81ce0e5-6844-3bee-be55-b09749bf9ad0> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libwbbase.dylib
       0x1054b2000 -        0x10552dfff libgrt.dylib (*) <afc8e17e-c733-3b91-9f71-e4a69a946fe4> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgrt.dylib
       0x105626000 -        0x10566dfff libmysql.canvas.dylib (*) <24242976-482b-3804-8034-3a604d954765> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libmysql.canvas.dylib
       0x104d77000 -        0x104d8afff libcdbc.dylib (*) <1dcdf163-882e-381b-a8d5-1e522b17a934> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libcdbc.dylib
       0x10606e000 -        0x1062d5fff libwbpublic.be.dylib (*) <dd4b666e-5b29-3417-8a35-f983d136e9bd> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libwbpublic.be.dylib
       0x10781c000 -        0x107ca7fff libwbprivate.be.dylib (*) <31b9640f-99af-3a11-9236-fd4870a1297a> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libwbprivate.be.dylib
       0x10695e000 -        0x106a81fff libmforms.dylib (*) <9d9adfd4-2623-37d1-88a3-4355603c1ff2> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libmforms.dylib
       0x105d51000 -        0x105fdcfff com.apple.python3 (3.9.6) <8c0dd12f-aa40-38c6-9ad8-c3276ba59c20> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3
       0x1086dc000 -        0x10890bfff libparsers.dylib (*) <9d5a124e-d40e-38c8-8239-1f2b8e306b28> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libparsers.dylib
       0x108d94000 -        0x10921bfff libmysqlcppconn.9.8.1.0.dylib (*) <fb5c443a-d090-352c-aa32-85f824e3f8f6> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libmysqlcppconn.9.8.1.0.dylib
       0x10577e000 -        0x1057c1fff WBExtras (*) <a536f1d3-80ff-364a-abe4-7e2df18d9818> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBExtras.framework/Versions/A/WBExtras
       0x1053c9000 -        0x105418fff libssh.4.8.7.dylib (*) <437229a9-dd83-3410-8520-6ea7a3413303> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libssh.4.8.7.dylib
       0x105a1b000 -        0x105b5afff libglib-2.0.0.dylib (*) <48c3197c-137a-3178-9b52-a95ba33c955f> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libglib-2.0.0.dylib
       0x107062000 -        0x1071a9fff com.sun.Scintilla (3.7.0) <79ef58f1-0dea-39f0-87e2-f96816fb419a> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/Scintilla.framework/Versions/A/Scintilla
       0x105341000 -        0x105384fff libpcre.1.dylib (*) <4c05c7fd-e2c6-34f2-a809-7d5f23776bc5> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libpcre.1.dylib
       0x104d50000 -        0x104d53fff libgmodule-2.0.0.dylib (*) <8259c65c-b4ed-305f-bc88-f92f6aadd038> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgmodule-2.0.0.dylib
       0x105bcb000 -        0x105c8efff libcairo.2.dylib (*) <b2aed4f9-1080-32f3-a3cb-3fbed0143a1e> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libcairo.2.dylib
       0x106dde000 -        0x106e7dfff libpixman-1.0.dylib (*) <5faef324-b180-3cff-8beb-472abe24b46b> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libpixman-1.0.dylib
       0x1052a1000 -        0x1052d0fff libpng16.16.dylib (*) <a81afd63-4df5-3c61-84ce-4cf2ec510d02> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libpng16.16.dylib
       0x106eb6000 -        0x106f21fff libantlr4-runtime.dylib (*) <9ebd10e3-f7a0-35a5-bab9-65683456e782> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libantlr4-runtime.dylib
       0x105909000 -        0x105970fff libssl.3.dylib (*) <caf1ef86-008a-3bb1-98ee-d057494e322a> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libssl.3.dylib
       0x10962c000 -        0x1098cffff libcrypto.3.dylib (*) <7b2d72ff-2bdd-326e-ad46-ddc81b1959c3> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libcrypto.3.dylib
       0x105399000 -        0x1053a4fff libmtemplate.dylib (*) <127a33d2-a9e8-34c0-9b3d-109a5682f4e8> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libmtemplate.dylib
       0x10aceb000 -        0x10b97afff libgdal.31.0.3.dylib (*) <0c42a24a-ddab-376b-afd9-b8e69ac99fcc> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgdal.31.0.3.dylib
       0x105451000 -        0x105464fff libvsqlitepp.3.dylib (*) <94ef0a00-8413-38b2-834e-7b2f12ba1ab9> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libvsqlitepp.3.dylib
       0x1074aa000 -        0x107621fff libsqlite3.so (*) <9f93bf84-ee9c-3b24-8a8e-00bfba2def99> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libsqlite3.so
       0x10a19f000 -        0x10a5befff libmysqlclient.21.dylib (*) <d15f8864-ff99-3f49-81a9-d039d1ef1942> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
       0x10bff3000 -        0x10c2cafff libproj.25.9.1.1.dylib (*) <9a981a95-84e2-37ad-a094-29543e529d57> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libproj.25.9.1.1.dylib
       0x10586e000 -        0x105881fff libwbssh.dylib (*) <d537b38f-4a91-316b-
```

Comment: MySQL 8.0 для MacOS совместим только с MacOS 13. Вряд-ли это поможет, но можете попробовать обновиться до MySQL 8.1 https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/